# How to autofill cells with data from another table?

Tags: excel

It's probably a stupid question. I'm a beginner and I couldn't find a solution on Google.

So I've got an Excel file with two sheets.
Sheet1 has a lot of data and I want to display only parts of this data in Sheet2.

Sheet1 looks like this:
There is column B, and starting from B6 I want to display every 11th cell in Sheet2.

Sheet2 is supposed to look like this:
I want to create one column that displays B6, B17, B28, B39, B50... from Sheet1.

I've used =Sheet1!B6, =Sheet1!B17, =Sheet1!B28, ...
But I want to duplicate this formula a lot of times, with an increment of 11 cells. If I just pull down it only increments the cells downwards by 1.

Can someone help me quickly with this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,5+ROW()*11)` do what you want? (you may need to tweak this to get the exact rows you want)

Comment: You can try to use index, or offset or indirect

Comment: Okey I'm figuring it out now, I think it will work with =INDEX in the end. I will post the result. Thank you!

Comment: Result looks pretty complicated now, but it works: =INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B;(ROW(Sheet1!$B6)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$6))*11+6)